# Streaming video on ubuntu 18

Tags: video, streaming

**Update**, i installed wine, took a long time on my i5-6200U, 8GB 2133 ram, 1TB wd hdd, but it is no where to be found. Can not start windows .exe or .com downloaded programs. (Perhaps that is a clue on it self?)

This aside i saw vlc and parole. 
These can handle streaming aswel. 
In Parole after 'loading'  the video url http://185.176.192.24/vids/charlies_angels_season_1_-_episode_08___578a21c20b417.mp4  from sochshare, it gives the error : Error from Gstreamer background service, bad request.
I checked and al Gstreamer 'packages' are installed.
Wel, i see 12, all installed.

For the first time in like 12 years, i installed ubuntu Bionic Beaver and it works with all my laptops internals!

All but one thing, sockshare . net video's

I found answers from de-instaling codecs, add a repository and install one big package of them. 
Flash is installed. 
As a newbie i dont know the sudo, apt get and such commands anymore, but no errors. It all de-installed, or installed as i have read. Having to work with windows a lot, i even did many restarts, just to be sure all was loading/starting up.

Then the video seemed to stream, it said loading video in the centre of a moving circle, just as i seen many times before, but that is it, no streamed video.

1 of the 'solutions' i found was install chrome and it should work. Nope.
Add a vpn plugin to chrome, i did, works fine, but no video stream in sockshare

So i hope someone like that website too and got it to work, with what.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! i now can stream sockshare net in ubuntu 18 bionic beaver

I needed an extention for the seperatdly installed chrome : 
agent switcher, a white face with thick black glasses icon. 
It did not work at once, i also had to reinstall flash. 
And i had to install the Hardware Abstraction Layer for Proprietary Steams
Then after restart i used an chrome extention, the agent switcher, a.k.a ua spoofer, as apple safari 7, and blam, it streams!

Instal the Hardware Abstraction Layer for Proprietary Steams

```
sudo apt-get install hal
```

reinstall the flash plugin

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge flashplugin-installer && sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```